# how to get ancestor positioned element of an absolute element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML. I have read that

> "An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed)."

So how to find that nearest positioned ancestor element?

Comment: you do inspect element, go to the absolute positioned elements and then you check each ancestor using the dev tool

Comment: what use do you have for the ancestor?

Comment: @madalinivascu — The question says "in javascript"

Answer (score 5):

There is a property called `offsetParent` for element object. ex:

```
document.getElementById("ElementId").offsetParent
```

Comment: Hi Kiran I've been using JavaScript for a decade and I still needed to look this up - thanks for asking the question and answering it!